# Facebook Messenger Bots: Image Caching

Tags: facebook, caching, express, bots, messenger

I am building a bot for FB Messenger. One of the scenarios require using the [Generic Template](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/generic-template) of the sendAPI. However, it seems like FB Messenger is caching the images included in the template. Is there a way to avoid that?

One thing to note here is that I am using ExpressJS and I am serving the images through a normal controller using res.sendFile(..) as opposed to serving them as static files. I also disabled caching using the following:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
  res.header('Expires', '-1');
  res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
  next()
});
```

Comment: In addition to the updates you made, I also tried setting the Last-Modified, but FB Messenger does not respect that